# Using Alibaba Cloud, however nothing resolves to node.js express page

Tags: node.js, express, alibaba-cloud

I have an Alibaba ECS. At first, I moved some local node.js express scripts over. There were no errors. But typing in the internet IP(And yes, I did specify a port) I realized that it would not resolve. Anyone knows how to solve it or what the problem is? Like I said, there were no errors, strangly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never try Alibaba ECS before, but I did use Google Compute Engine and Amazon EC2, and can you check the "Security group" within your ECS, and maybe try to open few public ports like 80 and 443 and your application ports as well

Comment: I'll see, thanks :)

Comment: @FelixFong Thanks so much!! That was what I was missing!